# How to get a list of categories from database with php?

Tags: php, mysql, list, categories

I have a column in my database called 'category' that contains the name of the individual category that each blog post is in ('cars','books','movies').

I need to create a list that contains each of these categories.

When I query the database and echo all my categories I get a list with many duplicates (as expected).

Example:

- books
- books
- books
- cars
- movies
- movies

But what if I just want to display each individual category. How is this done? Can somebody point me to an online resource for this.

example:

- books
- cars
- movies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `DISTINCT` keyword:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category FROM posts;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `distinct`

`select distinct categoryname from category`

Answer (score -1):

Use [DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) while querying database for categories.